# how to create a payapal's payment form?

Tags: paypal

I want to create a form for paypal payment. like this form. [image: this is form of payapal]

what i want is to make a simple paypal button. after clicking on that button this form will appear. but the problem is when ever I create get payment button , from my paypal account I end up with this kind of form. [image] 
how to get that form in paypal? thanks in advance.
in addition i got a project code. this code is a paypal button link up with a form like my first image.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="ZEFZFYBY2SZB8">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

when i make a button from my paypal account. after click that button i end up with the form like my second image. how do i create the form like first image.

Comment: What is the programming language you are using?

Comment: php but it suppose to be create from paypal. in my paypal account i didn't get any option of it.

Comment: Then what problem are you facing exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Describe what kind of Script or CMS you are using is it PHP or HTML or .... ?

for Creating a button Login to your Paypal Account on Seller preferences and make the botton or find information [Here](https://www.paypal.com/US/webapps/mpp/merchant/solutions/paypal-button)

if you are using Wordpress and Woocommerce you can install plugins [Here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/paypal-express-checkout/)

if you are using PHP Scripts you can find Code Integration [Here](https://www.spaceotechnologies.com/paypal-payment-gateway-integration-php/)

**UPDATE**

Regarding your Type of Form you wanted you can download either one of the plugins written by Scott Paterson Below

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-paypal-add-on/

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/easy-paypal-donation/

The First Plugin is the Form that you referred on your comments below
just leave the price and form empty

Comment: i am using wordpress. but its not Woocommerce. and i already make a button but its not giving me the form what i want. the form i want is like my first image.

Comment: I write down a button code with my question. after click that button you will see a form of PayPal. how do I create that form in PayPal.

Comment: @MakdumulIslam you don't create forms in PayPal you create your forms in your code and integrate it with PayPal but if you can tell me what kind of storefront you are using in WP or it's just a native theme with stores then I can give you the simplest solution

Comment: @ CatChMeIfUCan. I am using just a native theme. I need a very simple thing. for example you can see this link [simple payment link](https://www.colorexpertsbd.com/payments). I just want to make some thing like this page simple payment way.

Comment: depends... the value is a specific value like 10$ ? or you need something like top up form? (like in your example)

Comment: If you click on PayPal icon you will see the form. There is no specific value like $10. There are only two field 1."price per item" and 2."quantity"

Comment: In my question the first image is the example of that form.

Comment: Thanks. for your help

Answer (score 1):

See following link which guides you to get started with using [Paypal Payment Gateway](https://phppot.com/php/paypal-payment-gateway-integration-in-php/) :

- https://phppot.com/php/paypal-payment-gateway-integration-in-php/

Comment: what I am looking for its not PayPal Payment Gateway. I write down a button code with my question. after click that button you will see a form of PayPal. how do I create that form in PayPal.

Comment: @MakdumulIslam That is handled by your PayPal account. Check your account settings.